# Spacy v3 custom sentence segmentation

Tags: python, spacy, sentence, spacy-3

I want to split into sentences a large corpus (.txt) **only** using a custom delimiter i.e. `{S}` . I am working with Spacy 3.1.

Taking as an example the following sentence, which should be considered as one :

```
{S} — Quel âge as -tu? demanda Angel. — Je ne sais pas, — Sais -tu faire la soupe ?{S}
```

Spacy returns :

```
{S}
—
Quel âge as
-tu?
demanda Angel.
— Je ne sais pas, —
Sais
-tu faire la soupe ?
```

I have already tried the following with no luck :

```
@Language.component("segm")
def set_custom_segmentation(doc):
    for token in doc[:-1]:
        if token.text == '{S}':
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = False
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe('segm', first=True)
```

as well as a rule to consider {S} as a single token :

```
special_case = [{ORTH: "{S}"}]
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("{S}", special_case)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `token.is_sent_start = True` to add sentence boundaries, so something more like:

```py
@Language.component("segm")
def set_custom_segmentation(doc):
    for token in doc[:-1]:
        if token.text == '{S}':
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = True
        else:
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = False
    return doc
```

Comment: This works, thank you! To be honest, I do not understand the ` doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = False` condition so if you have time/don't mind could you please explain it briefly ?

Comment: I tried to have a "longer" delimiter like : {{S}} or {S} (i.e. {S} always followed by a whitespace) and it just merged all the sentences into a huge one. Is this normal ?

Comment: `is_sent_start` can be `True`, `False`, or `None` (unset). If it's `None`, then the parser (or potentially other components) may add an additional sentence boundary. If it's `False`, the parser won't modify it.